# how can i get the longest text in column of gridex janus?

Tags: c#, winforms, janus, gridex

In Gridex Janus, you can double-click a column header (actually the line between 2 column headers) and the column to the left will expand in width to fit the length of the longest text. Is there a way to get the longest text programmatically?

Comment: Yes, there is. You can use [TextRenderer.MeasureText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext(v=vs.110).aspx). But if your goal is making the column size larger programmatically, the control most likely have built-in support for auto-sized columns.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to resize all columns try using

```
GridEx.autosizeColumns()
```

if not try this linq code that returns max len for each column in a datatable (assuming at least one non-null value in each column, otherwise, Max will throw an exception)

```
List<int> maximumLengthForColumns = 
Enumerable.Range(0, dataTable.Columns.Count)
         .Select(col => dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                                 .Select(row => row[col]).OfType<string>()
                                 .Max(val => val.Length)).ToList();
```

or use this code to get maximum length in the whole table

```
int maxLength = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                          .SelectMany(row => row.ItemArray.OfType<string>())
                          .Max(str => str.Length);
```